# Underlying storage and functionality of unordered_maps vs unordered_multimaps in C++?

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable, unordered-map, multimap

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around unordered_maps and unordered_multimaps because my test code isn't producing what I've been told to expect.

```
std::unordered_map<string, int> names;

names.insert(std::make_pair("Peter", 4));

names.insert(std::make_pair("George", 4));

names.insert(std::make_pair("George", 4));
```

When I iterate through this list, I get one instance of George first, then Peter.

1) It's my understanding unordered_maps do not allow multiple keys to map to one value, and that multimaps due. Is this true?

2) Why can Peter and George coexist at a value of 4? What is happening to the second George? And for that matter, why is George appearing first when I iterate from begin() to end() if this is unordered?

3) What is the underlying representation of an unordered map vs. unordered multimap?

4) Is there a way to insert keys into either map without providing a value? E.g. have the compiler create its own hash function that I don't need to worry about when I retrieve keys and look for collisions?

Comment: I think you should read some more on maps vs sets, maps map keys onto values, sets, however, only store things.

Comment: Maps don't allow duplicate keys, while multimaps do. Neither cares whether or not there are duplicate values - only keys matter. They don't generally even know how to compare values - you can have a class as a value that doesn't define `operator==` nor `operator<`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make it short:

1. No. Multi... refers to keys. A (non-multi)map can't have multiple equivalent keys with differeny values, ie. per key there is at most one value. A multi map can. The same holds for the unordered versions.
2. `Peter != George`, which is why they have different key and may very well have the same value.
3. A hashmap.
4. Use sets.

In your example the second insertion for `George` using a (non-multi) is skipped  as the same key was previously inserted.

Comment: >"In your example the second insertion for George using a (non-multi) map would overwrite the previously inserted pair." 

No it won't overwrite it.

Comment: No, you won't be. First of all, read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert and then test it yourself, if you don't believe me: http://ideone.com/ruG2Kh .

Answer (score 1):

You want to use unordered_multimap to have several keys that are the same.

Since this is unordered you can't really hope to have any particular order, because it depends on the hash function.

If you want order in which you insert things, you need to use std::vector. Even normal maps, which are supposed to be ordered imply the comparison order, and not the order in which you insert things, for example string "AB" comes before "BB", because "A" is less than "B".

To insert without providing a value you need a set, and not a map.

The underlying structure of "unordered_" things is hashtable.